# Differences between Fprint/Fprintf vs conn.Write

Tags: go, encryption, printf

I am trying to send encrypted data across a TCP connection. Fprintf works fine for unencrypted data but seems to be adding formatting to encrypted data causing the decrypt to fail intermittently. I am unable send using conn.Write or for that matter writer.Writestring followed by writer.Flush().

```
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() && err == nil {
        msg := scanner.Text()
            ciphertext := edlogic.Encrypt([]byte(msg+"\n")
            conn.Write(append(ciphertext, '\r'))
    }

    //Receiver
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)
        for scanner.Scan() {
        ciphertext := scanner.Bytes()
        plaintext := edlogic.Decrypt(ciphertext)
        fmt.Println(string(plaintext))
        }
```

Comment: `Scanner` by default scans lines, delimited by `\n` or `\r\n`. Your lines are delimited by `\r` only (the `\n` you're appending is before encryption so it is no longer a `\n` on the wire).

Comment: What's md5.Encrypt and md5.Decrypt ? Hash(md5) and encryption/decryption?

Comment: can you post a working example including all imports. With import "crypto/md5" I get "undefined md5.Encrypt", so I wonder what this is.

Comment: @jps, from your first comment I realized that md5 is a reserved keyword. I had named the package where the encrypt/decrypt code lives as md5. I renamed it now. Thanks for your and Adrian's responses.

Comment: No, md5 is not a reserved keyword, but just the name of a hashing algorithm which is also used in the package crypto/md5. But the combination of md5 and decrypt is really strange, there's nothing to decrypt on a hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few points here that are going to hopefully help you figure out why this isn't working. I am assuming that whatever encryption method you're using inside `edlogic` is using the correct keys on both sides of this transaction because we have no insight into what cryptography you're actually using. If you're unsure if you're doing this right, try writing a separate program to encrypt some known plain text, inspect it to be sure the cipher text looks nothing like your plain text, decrypt it, and compare it to the original input to be sure it matches. If your encryption doesn't work then transferring it over TCP won't fix it.

Your scanner use on the sender side seems ok but the scanner on the receiver side is going to have issues. For one, everything @Adrian said in their comment is correct. You're encrypting your `\n`, you're then appending `\r` and then the scanner on the receiving end is looking for `\n`. This is problematic and annoyingly the solution is not to simply append `\n` instead of `\r`. To know why, you'll need to learn a detail or two about cryptography.

Hashing, encrypting, decrypting, whatever you're doing in modern cryptography you're almost always acting on bytes. Input. Output. All the in-between parts you don't see. Bytes. There is absolutely zero guarantee about what these bytes will hold. In theory every byte has an equal chance of containing any value between and including 0 and 255. There will by null bytes, ASCII looking bytes, maybe valid unicode, for all you know the output is dozens of poop emoji. The point is that the only safe assumption is that the output bytes ("cipher text" as you properly labeled it but remember, not text in the traditional sense) won't look like the input bytes ("plain text", also doesn't have to be text, you can encrypt binary files. Decrypted cipher text is also called plain text).

After you encrypt your message, there might be new line bytes in the raw output. You can't use a sentinel value like the new line character as a divider. The simplest alternative is to encode the bytes in base64 (`import "encoding/base64"`) and send that. Now you can safely choose a sentinel that isn't in the base64 character set. Use `\n` and a Scanner and it'll work like you expect.

On the sender side you should:

1. Encrypt the plain text to get cipher text
2. Encode the cipher text as base64
3. Append a newline to the base64
4. Transmit the data using `conn.Write`

On the other receiver side you're now able to:

1. Use a scanner to receive the encrypted chunk of cipher text encoded in base64
2. Base64 decode the received bytes back to it's cipher text
3. Decrypt the cipher text to plain text
4. Do whatever you want to do with the plain text

EDIT: I know this doesn't answer the exact question you answered. For completeness, here's that answer:

`Fprint` will print everything you give it to the `Writer` but will attempt to format the other parameters to a string first. This is not a good way to send bytes. `fmt.Fprint(os.Stdout, []byte{1, 2, 3})` does not write 3 bytes with the values of 1, 2, and 3. It writes 7 bytes, the string `[1 2 3]` because that's how fmt's default formatter formats byte arrays/slices.

`Fprintf` gives you a little more control. You can use formatting "verbs" to override the default formatter. For byte arrays/slices, you can use %s to parse the bytes as a string (not recommended unless you know all the bytes are valid unicode), %x and %X to print the bytes in hex using either lowercase or uppercase letters respectively, and %v will use the default formatter which will print all the bytes' decimal values separated by spaces and book ended by square brackets. It's still not a good fit for writing bytes as the bytes they are.

I would assume that `conn` came from a `net.Dial(...)` or something similar which would probably make it the interface `net.Conn`. Things written to it stay as bytes without going through any formatting, mapping, or other "tampering."

Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: your response works like a charm. I tested the code with an encrypt/decrypt example from https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/02/encrypt-decrypt-data-golang-application-crypto-packages/. Thanks.